# Nintex Forms 2013 - Conditional text

Tags: sharepoint-2013, nintex-workflow

I am using NINTEX FORMS, no previous experience, and I want to set the value of a tag's text based on the value of a key I send through the query string.

What I am trying to accomplish is something like this:

```
If(fn-GetQueryString(TipoSolicitud) = "X", "Text1", "Text2")
```

But this doesn't work at all. Anyone knows if this is possible? and How to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use "fn-If" instead of "If" in your formula.
The correct formula should be like this:

`fn-If(fn-Equals(fn-GetQueryString("TipoSolicitud"),"X"),"equal","not equal")`